# Why is human life limited according to Hinduism?

Tags: puranas

Why is the human life limited? Why is it not infinite like gods .

This would help the humans to correct our mistakes and to lead a peaceful life without any greed or fear of losing any one.

Why god gave us limited life?

Comment: This may be a little abstruse but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBjE6d_JmQI

Comment: @moonstar2001nice ..good concept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Life by its nature of being real aware existence is eternal. What is limited is the duration of the body with which life gets identified. The identification with a body is due desires of the identity "I am" which life creates. The body and identification with it in any number of bodily birth is governed by predispositions and latent tendencies appearing in mind. They are the result also of bodily actions with strong desires in the past. Gods do not have desires that bind and therefore are free of predispositions and latent tendencies; there is no karma for them.